FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'possible_successors.pickle'
I am trying to run a python code in the command prompt of Windows. I set the workdirectory to the current .py file that I want to run. Neverthless, when the code has to open a file called possible_successors.pickle, it says that the file is not there even if that file is in the current working directory. How can I fix the problem?
I tried to locate this .pickle file somewhere else, but still I get the same issue.

Hello, please include a minimal reproducable example so we can solve your problem. In your case I think you should attach your code, and possibly the list of files in your working directory, for example the result of dir in command prompt.

If the OS says the file doesn't exist then it doesn't exist. Try using an absolute pathname to the file

Without any code example is difficult to know what is the problem.But with this code you should be able to load the file.
import os
import pickle

with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'possible_successors.pickle'), 'rb') as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)

